# Format and replace a string with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a number that's at least 7 digits long.
Typical examples: `0000123`, `00001234`, `000012345`

I want to transform them so that they become respectively:
`01:23`, `12:34`, `23:45`

Which mean replacing the whole string by the last 4 characters and putting a colon in the middle.

I can get the last 4 digits with `(\d{4})$`
And I can get 2 groups with this: `(\d{2})(\d{2})$`

With the last option, on a string `0000123` $1:$2 match gives me `00001:23`
where I want `01:23`

I replace the string like so:

```
newVal = val.replace(/regex/, '$1:$2');
```

Comment: No need for an RE: `time =  val.substr(val.length - 4, 2) + ":" +  val.substr(-2);` ?

Comment: @gyc which language.?

Comment: @AlexK.: Since you didn't post an answer, I posted a CW with that, as it frankly seems the simplest, most straight-forward way to do it. But if you decide to post it, let me know and I'll delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the beginning digits with `\d*` (or with just `.*` if there can be anything):

```js
var val = "0001235";
var newVal = val.replace(/^\d*(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, '$1:$2');
console.log(newVal);
```

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d*` - 0+ digits (or `.*` will match any 0+ chars other than line break chars)
- `(\d{2})` - Group 1 capturing 2 digits
- `(\d{2})` - Group 2 capturing 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Or as the digit string is known to be at least 7 digits you could match it with `\d{3,}(\d{2})(\d{2})` and then any shorter digit strings will be skipped.

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 2):

[As Alex K. said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374244/format-and-replace-a-string-with-a-regular-expression#comment77709519_45374244), no need for a regular expression, just extract the parts you need with [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
val = val.substr(-4, 2) + ":" + val.substr(-2);
```

Note that when the starting index is negative, it's from the end of the string.

Example:

```js
function update(val) {
  return val.substr(-4, 2) + ":" + val.substr(-2);
}
function test(val) {
  console.log(val + " => " + update(val));
}
test("0000123");
test("0001234");
test("000012345");
```

Comment: Correct, this is a good solution. In my particular case there are other regex manipulations above my code and I feel the regex version will be helpful if the parsing becomes more complex later in the project.

Comment: @gyc: Fair enough, but frankly, I'd introduce it later in the project **if** it becomes necessary, and keep it simple until then.

Comment: Yes definitely. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex: `^(\d+?)(\d{2})(\d{2})$`:

```js
var newVal = "0000123".replace(/^(\d+?)(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, '$2:$3');
console.log(newVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could throw the first characters away and the replace only the last matched parts.

```js
console.log('00000001234'.replace(/^(.*)(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, '$2:$3'));
```